# Sum of reciprocals of primorial numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, primorial

What is the following sum?

$x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\times 3}+\frac{1}{2\times 3\times 5}+...$

$=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i}$, where $p_i$ is the $i^{th}$ prime.

I'm guessing this converges to 1 using the following logic.

The sieve of Eratosthenes works as follows.

From the set $N$ of all natural numbers we first remove all multiples of 2, that is half the numbers. Then from the remaining half we remove all multiples of 3, which will amount to removing one sixth of the numbers from $N$ because $1/6=1/2\times 1/3$. Repeating this process, next we remove all multiples of 5, that is, we will remove $1/2\times 1/3\times 1/5=1/30^{th}$ more numbers from $N$. If we continue this process indefinitely, in the end we would have removed $x$ fraction of the numbers and the remaining $1-x$ fraction are the primes. Since the ratio $\pi(n)/n$ approaches 0 as $n$ approaches infinity, Hence $1-x = 0$ or $x = 1$.

Comment: Compare to the geometric series 1/2 + 1/4 + ... to see that the limit must be smaller than 1...

Comment: https://oeis.org/A064648

Comment: Similar to @AnneBauval 's OEIS link, here is the computation for the first 300 primes in WolframAlpha: [**link**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+from+n%3D1+to+300+%28product+from+k%3D1+to+n+of+1%2Fprime%5Bk%5D%29)

Comment: Lots of digits, using Sage: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNjMEKAiEURffzFZdZacnk1C4Q%2DhOZyhkf1Ev0gb%2DfSURndw7ceyGWkJebDPewwqtI7mStPg9oFAOBgzWYu6%2DvjARipEzP4PPCW1BHg0jfwQfBziH9tGDvMB%2Dkh9reZLqS%2DEfgTaLSPbc7FjW2XkaD%2Dh%5FLxKpq%5FQYZ9SsA&lang=sage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sieve argument could consider:

- $\frac12$ to remove the even numbers
- $(1-\frac12)\frac13 =\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}$ to remove the odd multiples of $3$
- $(1-(1-\frac12)\frac13)\frac15 =\frac{5}{2\cdot 3 \cdot 5} $ to remove the multiples of $5$ which are not multiples of $2$ or $3$
- $(1-(1-(1-\frac12)\frac13)\frac15)\frac17 =\frac{25}{2\cdot 3 \cdot 5\cdot 7} $ to remove the multiples of $7$ which are not multiples of $2$ or $3$ or $5$
- and so on

You can see the third term of $\frac{5}{2\cdot 3 \cdot 5}$ is not your third term of $\frac{1}{2\cdot 3 \cdot 5}$, which would instead be multiples of $30$ though those have already been removed.  Similarly with later terms.

The sum of those four terms is $\frac{20}{21}\approx 0.95238$, already much closer to $1$ than your infinite series which sums to just over $0.70523$.

Comment: The denominators are the primorial numbers,  while the numerators are the alternating sum of primorial numbers as in [OEIS A265184](https://oeis.org/A265184) but without signs